# facebook socialite API redirect to the callback url without validating fb login form

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

While implenting fb login in my laravel website, without displaying the fb login form, it is redirecting to the facebook callback url which I have set in my env file.

Why this is happening?  Any help is appreciated.

`https://www.cheerzclub.com/auth/facebook` - this is the `facebookRedirect` API's url
`https://www.cheerzclub.com/auth/facebook/callback` - this is the `loginWithFacebook` API's url

**controller code**

```
class SocialController extends Controller
{
    public function facebookRedirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }
    
    public function loginWithFacebook(Request $r)
    {
        if (!$r->has('code') || $r->has('denied')) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();
        }
        
        $isUser = User::where('fb_id', $user->id)->first();
        if (!$isUser)
            $isUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
        if (!$isUser)
            $isUser = User::where('email', $user->id)->first();
        if ($isUser) {
            Auth::login($isUser);
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
            $createUser = User::create([
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email ? $user->email : $user->id,
                'fb_id' => $user->id,
                'email_verified_at' => now(),
                'password' => Hash::make('SLogin#123')
            ]);
            Auth::login($createUser);
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    }
```

This is my **Network tab screenshot** which clearly shows that redirection.

[image: Network tab screenshot]

But the same API properly returns the fb login page when tried this APi in postman.
**postman screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: _"Why this is happening?"_ - Because you have already logged into that app before ...? That's how it is supposed to work - once the user has granted the permissions the app asks for, they won't be asked _again_ the next time. As long as they are logged in to Facebook, they will simply be redirected back to your app "silently", without any further interference.

Comment: Try in incognito. Also run - "php artisan optimize:clear".

Comment: @CBroe I have never logged into facebook from my system before

Comment: Someone else logged into Facebook in the browser that you are testing in then ...? Your first screenshot clearly shows, that it goes from your /auth/facebook endpoint to Facebook, and then from there back to your callback endpoint - _with_ a `code` parameter. That would not happen, if Facebook did not find a logged-in user.

Comment: @CBroe u r correct. there was a fb logged in the device. thanks